# Finding lowest and highest number number value in an Array

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am struggling to workout how this code is working, how is the maxNum part working? maxNum[0] < numbers[i] how is it grabbing the last number from the array?

```js
function sortThem(numbers) {

  let minNum = numbers[0]
  let maxNum = numbers[0]

  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (minNum > numbers[i]) {
      minNum = numbers[i]
    } else if (maxNum < numbers[i]) {
      maxNum = numbers[i]
    }
  }

  console.log(maxNum)

  const minMax = [minNum, maxNum]
  return minMax

}

const results = sortThem([2, 9, 10, 17, 45])

console.log(results)
```

Comment: unclear what is not clear. Your log is outside the loop, maybe if you added it inside the loop it would be more clear. It goes over every index of the array It looks to see if the number is the smallest. If that fails it checks to see the number is the largest. Read it out load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both start at 2 in this example

```
let minNum = numbers[0]//equals first element in the numbers array and thats 2 in this example
let maxNum = numbers[0]// equals 2 as well
```

Then you start to iterate thru the numbers array

Lets cover how you get your lowest number first:

```
if(minNum > numbers[i]){

1st loop
minNum = 2 not greater than 2, nothing happens
2nd loop 
minNum = 2 not greater than 9, nothing happens
3rd loop
minNum = 2 not greater than 10, nothing happens
4th loop
minNum = 2 not greater than 17, nothing happens
last loop
minNum = 2 not greater than 45, nothing happens
```

minNum = never changes during the entire iteration becuz no number lesser than 2 was found so it keeps the initial value

Now for the maxNum:

```
 } else if (maxNum < numbers[i]){

1st loop
maxNum= 2, numbers[i]=2, numbers[i] not greater than maxNum, nothing happens
2nd loop 
maxNum= 2, numbers[i]=9, numbers[i] is greater than maxNum, maxNum=9 now
3rd loop
maxNum= 9, numbers[i]=10, numbers[i] is greater than maxNum, maxNum=10 now
4th loop
maxNum= 10, numbers[i]=17, numbers[i] is greater than maxNum, maxNum=17 now
last loop
maxNum= 17, numbers[i]=45, numbers[i] is greater than maxNum, maxNum=45 now
```

maxNum will overwrite itself as long as you can find a number that's higher than the value previously stored.
Hopefully that explains what you don't understand

Comment: ahhhhh, thats it, so it keeps overwriting itself until the end of the array, I that penny moment people keep telling me about has just happened, nice one Chris. :D

Comment: yeah and it works even if your highest number is at the beggining of the array, maxNum will store 45 for example and it will never overwrite itself during the loop because no other element is higher than that. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Given to a context I dont fully get I would estimate that you want to know how the comparison works.

```js
function sortThem(numbers) {

  let minNum = numbers[0]
  let maxNum = numbers[0]

  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { // you can start loop at index 1 since you have set default val to 0
    if (minNum > numbers[i]) { // if my current number in array is smaller than the most recent minNum
      minNum = numbers[i] // set minNum to current number Exit out of if/else structure since else will not be triggered
    } else if (maxNum < numbers[i]) { // if currentNumber is greater than given maxNum
      maxNum = numbers[i] //set maxnum to current number
    }
  }

  console.log(maxNum)

  const minMax = [minNum, maxNum] //useless
  return minMax // return [minNum, maxNum];

}

const results = sortThem([2, 9, 10, 17, 45])

console.log(results)
```

No Idea if it answered your question, but I think thats the explanation of this function.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I think what is confusing me is the else if section, the way I am looking at it is 2 < 2, 2 < 9, 2 < 10 etc etc so from my logic 2 < 9 so would stop, as 2 less than 9 I hope that makes sense.

Comment: 2 > 2 = not true, since 2 equals 2 and is not larger. Since it is false you go to the else section. In the else Section you check whether the number is larger than your max number. if it is equal or smaller, you already have your max number for the current iteration (found it in an earlier iteration). So nothing left there and you can continue with the loop. 

If 2 > 1 you have a new minimum, and since you startet with the same number in the first place, there is no chance that the max number is smaller than the new minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You define `minNum` and `maxNum`, which start with being just some value from the array (in this case index 0 / the first one, which is 2).

`for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { /* ...*/ }`
means everything inside {} will be repeated the same amount of times that the array has indexes, and every iteration `i` will be increased by one (starting with 0, so it will loop over all indexes of numbers array)

so `numbers[i]` gets value at `i`th position (first time it will be `2`, second time `9`...)

The if conditions check whether the current `minNum`/`maxNum` is smaller/greater than value at `i`th index of numbers array, and if it is, it sets `minNum`/`maxNum` to that value, so it is increased / decreased.

Basically the code goes trough every value in the array you defined, and everytime it finds bigger value, it sets it as value for `minNum`/`maxNum`.

In this case `minNum` is set to 2, and because it is the smallest of all, it stays 2.
`maxNum` starts at 2, is increased to 9, 10, 17 and then to 45.

Answer (score 0):

Although, its an easy implementation. It'll be better if you dry run the loop using a pen and paper. I'll write the algo you have used so that it becomes easier for you.

1. You take an array as an input.
2. You initialize 2 vars (namely minNum and maxNum) to the value of the First
   element from the array
3. Run a loop over the array, to check and update the values of minNum and
   maxNum.
4. After the loop ends, you return those numbers in an array.
   That's it!